# Unique Constraint in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, unique-constraint

I need to reject at indexing time if same value in the same field is found in a different document.For example if I register with one username ,next time I should not register with the same username, like how we are using unique constraint in other databases oracle,mysql etc...Can someone help me how to achieve this in ElasticSearch..

Thanks,
SP

Answer (score 0):

If the username is unique, you can use it as the _id of your document.
For instance you index your username1 using a bulk request:

```
POST /_bulk
{ "create" : { "_index" : "myindex", "_type" : "mytype", "_id" : "username1" } }
{ "name" : "username1", "adress" : "adress of my username.." }
```

The result will be:

```
"create": {
            "_index": "myindex",
            "_type": "mytype",
            "_id": "username1",
            "_version": 1,
            "status": 201
         }
```

Then if you try to index a new document with the same id "username1":

```
POST /_bulk
{ "create" : { "_index" : "myindex", "_type" : "mytype", "_id" : "username1" } }
{ "name" : "name2", "adress" : "adress of my username.." }
```

you will get an exception:

```
"create": {
            "_index": "myindex",
            "_type": "mytype",
            "_id": "username1",
            "status": 409,
            "error": "DocumentAlreadyExistsException[[myindex][3] [mytype][username1]: document already exists]"
         }
```

Of course you can still update your username if needed:

```
POST /_bulk
{ "update" : { "_index" : "myindex", "_type" : "mytype", "_id" : "username1" } }
{ "doc" : {"name" : "updatedusername1", "adress" : "adress of my username.." }}
```

And this will return:

```
"update": {
            "_index": "myindex",
            "_type": "mytype",
            "_id": "username1",
            "_version": 2,
            "status": 200
         }
```

Notice the `"_version": 2`

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.But as per my requirement _id should be auto generated and I need one more unique field in the document say "UserName".How to achieve this.Please give your suggestion's on this.

Comment: The `_id` is the only field that can have the uniqueness restriction in Elasticsearch. The only way I see you could achieve it is to query first Elasticsearch to check if the username is already here. But this means to request to Elasticsearch... What the reason you want to use auto generated _id ? If you have a field with uniqueness is a good reason to use it as _id and should not affect performance